# Visual Studio Project GUIDS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint

Following on from this question...

["how do you tell the visual studio project type from an existing visual studio project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660790/how-do-you-tell-the-visual-studio-project-type-from-an-existing-visual-studio-pro)

How do i add project guids into my csproj file to enable me to add other types of form/controls.

For instance I create a class project solution and want to be able to add web forms and web user controls to the project.

I attended a talk where the presenter showed this was possible but he didn't supply any further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy.  Just edit the web project.  Add the necessary guids as shown in my post, [How to Hack a Class Library Project into a Web Application Project](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/02/22/how-to-hack-a-class-library-project-into-a-web-application-project.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Close the project, open the project file in a text or XML editor, and add the guids manually.

(Keep an original copy, it make take a few attempts to get right.)

Comment: I'm trying that by adding this line... 

<ProjectGuid>{ABF1B333-B149-4DBF-B1D7-B66438F14AD9};{349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21};{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}</ProjectGuid> 

which should give me the class, web app and web site. However i still don't have any additional forms.