# How can I find out what type of c# project I'm using in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I don't know a lot about c# or Visual Studio and I am working on a c# project, but I don't know the details of it. For example if it's a Desktop project, an Asp.net project, a .Net framework project, or what libraries it has access to.

How can I find this out?

Comment: have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660790/how-do-you-tell-the-visual-studio-project-type-from-an-existing-visual-studio-pr

Comment: Share your solution screen shot.

Comment: if your solution having .aspx pages then it asp.net application

Comment: The most accurate way is to open the csproj file in Notepad, and locate its project type GUID. Then by searching on Google you should be able to know the exact project type.

Comment: Hmm I found this in App.config: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: That is just the version of the runtime it should run with

Comment: Lexi Li, where can I find the csproj file?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the info Novaterata

Comment: Right-click the project and Unload it, then right-click and you can edit it

Comment: You can Right-click and Reload once you are done. It's kind of annoying honestly, especially for wixproj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click the project and go to properties it will provide you with the information that you're looking for.

Comment: @Identicon And create dummy projects for the different types you mentioned then compare their properties / references / project file structures so you can develop an intuition

Comment: Thanks for the tip Novaterata. Bill, could you elaborate on what you mean by "right click the project?" Do you mean the .sln file?

Comment: @Identicon Open the solution in Visual Studio and then right click the project in the solution explorer panel.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I see that I'm working on a console application, but I'm not sure if this is the information I was looking for. I remember I tried compiling this program on another windows machine a few days ago, I think a Desktop Application, and it didn't have access to System.Text and many other things.

Comment: @Identicon Would you mind sharing your source code? It sounds like you are missing references to System.Text.

Comment: Oh, it was actually that I had not created a console application before, but some other kind. Thanks for your help!